# Spring Boot/Integration: Disabling JMX

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, jmx

Is it possible to disable the export for MBeans in Spring Integration via a configuration setting?

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Integration. I've disable JMX in Spring Boot via

```
endpoints.jmx.enabled: false
spring.jmx.enabled: false
```

However, I want to see some statistics about some Spring Integration Channels and Enpoints, so I added `@EnableIntegration` and `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`. I can see the MBeans now.

Is it possible to later disable the export of Spring Integration MBeans via some setting the application.yml (similar to how it is done in Spring Boot)?

Comment: That is already enabled by default so no need to add `@EnableIntegration` or at least the `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`. If you want to disable imx just set `spring.jmx.enabled=false` in your property file to completely disable JMX. Your setting only disables the exposure of health and metrics endpoints through JMX.

Comment: `spring.jmx.enabled` is already set to `false`, but the Spring Integration MBeans are still shown. I've added this info to the questions.

Comment: because you are enabling it again by adding `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport` you are basically bypassing Spring Boot here. As stated remove it and disable imx.

Comment: Yes, but by removing `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport` the Spring Integration MBeans no longer get exported, even if I later turn on JMX again using the `spring.jmx.enabled` property.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot auto config that should happen (although I'm not sure which version they added auto config for this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a specific property for the Spring Integration JMX. It is fully tied with the common JMX configuration for the whole Boot application.

If you are fine with the `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`, consider to introduce custom `@ConfigurationProperties` and perform similar `@ConditionalOnProperty` on that `@Configuration` which adds that `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`.

Comment: Ok, I have to define my own property, e.g. `spring.integration.jmx.enable` and then use `@ConditionalOnProperty` to turn the MBeans export on or off.